# CRM Data Migration using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, dynamics-crm-online, fetchxml, common-data-service

Am trying to migrate data from CRM online to Data Lake.

within Copy Activity of ADF, am using FetchXML to read data from CRM (CDM)

FetchXML:

```
<fetch>
  <entity name="cdm_location">
    <attribute name="cdm_gisid" />
    <attribute name="cdm_locationid" />
    <attribute name="cdm_locationtype" />
    <attribute name="cdm_name" />
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Issue is ADF looks and the Sample dataset of above source query and determines the columns to be extracted.  In my case column `cdm_gisid` within the sample dataset is `NULL` and hence this column is being ignored by ADF.

Is there a way in FetchXML saying `if column is null replace with 'Default Value'` so that ADF can see the column in the Sample Dataset.

[Or] is there better way in ADF to pull data from CDM, bringing every column irrespective if its null or not null.

Comment: There is no way to manipulate the data during the copy activity, it means that we can not replace with 'Default Value'.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use a column map which can be defined in the **Mapping** tab of your copy activity. This is a known issue and is recommend in the ADF/D365 documentation.

See the Important note in the following link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-dynamics-crm-office-365#dynamics-as-a-source-type